# Calculating Total Time Taken to Replicate

Tags: master-slave-replication, postgresql-11

I wanted to know whether there are any open source tools or in built functions for generating replication metrics. Basically i wanted to calculate the time difference between changes in the Master vs Slave

For eg :

Suppose I insert a million rows in a table in Master, I want to store the total time it took to replicate the same in the standby.

The values in pg_stat_replication are all real time and once all the wal files are streamed it doesn't show the lag anymore, hence i need a way to store the final value. Is there any way of doing this??

I would really appreciate your inputs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323355/how-to-check-the-replication-delay-in-postgresql

Comment: https://github.com/hilli/pg-replication-lag

Comment: https://sysadvent.blogspot.com/2017/12/day-12-monitoring-postgres-replication.html#toc_8

Comment: thanks..All of these are helpful..However, is there any way to calculate the total time taken??..All of these values will disappear once the wals are streamed..Is there any way of storing these values persistently.